# Name of variables and functions

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering

I have a script that I am trying to reverse but I am a little confused about many things.
1st- What are these variables names ? How can I know their meaning ?
2nd- Can someone tell me the meaning of this line of code ? I have been trying to understand it but I did not succeed.
There is the script:

```
var _0x3ea8cd = function (_0x1a81d6)
{
    while (--_0x1a81d6)
    {
        _0x52548a['push'](_0x52548a['shift']());
    }
};
```

Comment: There are no meaning.....

Comment: What an interesting answer

Comment: Removing variable name is obfuscation 101, so they're essentially just randomly chosen name by the obfuscator

Comment: You are looking at renamed variables either by a build script or an obfuscation script. So the variables have no meaning....

Comment: `_0x1a81d6` is presumably a number and `_0x52548a` an array. This takes the first _n - 1_ entries from the array and puts them at the end of the array. `while(--n) arr.push(arr.shift())`

Comment: Looking at the code.  It creates a function. reduces a number in a loop and swaps positions of elements in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In more readable format it is equivalent to the following with exception of not having the array data that I added

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];// _0x52548a variable

var offsetArray = function (offset){// change name of _0x1a81d6
    while (--offset){
        arr.push(arr.shift());// use arr instead of _0x52548a
    }
};
// usage
offsetArray(2)// use _0x3ea8cd(2) in original code
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))


// using original
var _0x52548a= [1,2,3,4,5];

var _0x3ea8cd = function (_0x1a81d6)
{
    while (--_0x1a81d6)
    {
        _0x52548a['push'](_0x52548a['shift']());
    }
};
_0x3ea8cd(2)
console.log('Using original')
console.log(JSON.stringify(_0x52548a))
```

Comment: I hope the OP realizes you made up the variable names since there is no way to know what the original script had.